Sorting tables in Excel containing formulas
I'm having what appears to be a common problem with sorting tables in Excel, when they contain formulas.
However, while most other people seem to have formulas in their tables referring to other tables or other sheets, I have formulas referring to other rows in the same table.
My table in the sheet at A1
Sorry about the "equals", but it kept saying I had code in my question when I put "=A2" etc., so I had to get creative!



Name
Wife




Richard
equals A3


Dulcie
equals A2


Steve
equals A5


Mary
equals A4


Chris
equals A7


Paul
equals A6



So it displays Richard's wife as Dulcie and Dulcie's wife as Richard etc.
All well and good!
Then I sort column 1 alphabetically A-Z and all the formulas in column 2 muck up and no-one's wife is correct any more.
I can see what's happening - when Steve moves down 3 places to the bottom, the formula goes down 3 rows too, from A5 to A8, which doesn't exist.
Anyone know of a clever way I can avoid this?
I tried absolute references, but that means they don't change at all, so Steve's wife stays pointing at $A$5, which is now Paul !
(Yes I know I could use a lookup function in some way, but just want to point to the cell)
Where I'm actually having the problem is in a larger spreadsheet with a much bigger formula in col 2, but still just trying to reference other rows in col 1
Hopefully that's enough info to explain my problem?
Thanks
